# The infinite graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to define the infinite (countable) graph which is constructed as follows?
[image]

Comment: The picture depicts a finite graph.

Comment: Where is the infinity!?

Comment: If I understand your picture correctly, let $V$ be the set of all dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$, and let $(p,q)$ be an edge if and only if $p = \frac{k}{2^n}$, where $k$ is an odd number (or $0$), and $q = p + \frac{1}{2^m}$ for some $m \geq n$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @WillBrian Yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: This easy question could be *community*. I had 1: a nicer construction, and 2: an axiomatization.

Answer (score 3):

To do this formally, first formulate a definition by induction, and then take the union.

The basis step is a graph $G_0$ with two vertices and one edge.

For the inductive step, assuming $G_i$ is defined, embed $G_i$ into a graph $G_{i+1}$ as follows: for any edge $a$---$b$ of $G_i$ that is not an edge of $G_{i-1}$, attach a new vertex $v_{a,b}$ and edges $a$---$v_{a,b}$, $v_{a,b}$---$b$.

Now define the final graph to be the union of the nested sequence of graphs $G_0 \subset G_1 \subset G_2 \subset \cdots$.

As said in the comments, this construction can also be encoded with a tiny bit of number theory.

Comment: In the construction of $G_{i+1}$, you probably want to add a new $v_{a,b}$ only for those edges $a-b$ of $G_i$ that were not already in $G_{i-1}$. Otherwise, a single edge $a-b$ will result in "new" vertices and edges at all later stages.

Comment: This is a right remark. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction @AndreasBlass